# How do we convert moment date in to a date object?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a manipulated date using moment as `moment().subtract(10, 'days')`.
I need this date in java Script date object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `moment().subtract(10, 'days').toDate()`.